Excel VBA ListRows.Add slow after Excel update
My Excel recently has become exceedingly slow.
Trying to find whereabouts the slowness lies, I stumbled upon the following code, which, on a newly created table, takes up to one minute to execute, the "Add" command. There maybe more issues, as Excel regularly becomes unresponsive, takes a long time to save files etc. However this is a simple sheet with very little VBA, and I cannot imagine why the "Add" takes so long, especially the initial Add past ListObject creation.
Set tExDividends = ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range(ws.Cells(iHeaderRow, iStartCol), ws.Cells(iHeaderRow, iStartCol + iCol - 1)), False, xlYes, 0)
tExDividends.Name = "ExDividends"
Dim lrow As ListRow
Set lrow = tExDividends.ListRows.Add


It seems that the August 26th update to version 2408 slowed the execution of VBA for a lot of people. See: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-with-macros-running-very-slow-after-latest/0c520822-8f56-4f1f-b191-0c24d66f946a

Rolled back the update as per instructions and It has worked!

I've added an answer indicating that the rollback may fix the problem. You should probably accept the answer, because other people continue to try to answer the question without noticing that the rollback already fixed that for you.

If you have the version 2408 (Build 16.0.17928.20114) – maybe also valid for other build versions –, released the 2024 August 26: the update seems to have greatly slowed VBA execution for several people.
After some investigation, for us, it seems to be the update of cells that takes a lot longer since the update.
The problem seems to impact both 32 and 64 bits versions.
EDIT
The slowness problems have been fixed in the new versions (starting from Version 2408 (Build 17928.20156)).
Previous answer
Rolling back to the version 2407 solves the problem.
Here is a link to a discussion about that in the community forum:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-with-macros-running-very-slow-after-latest/0c520822-8f56-4f1f-b191-0c24d66f946a

Did you start with a workbook and a large(er) amount of VBA code, then cut it down to just the bare minimum?  If so, it could be that the Excel workbook itself is corrupt. Start with a brand new workbook and use the test code below. In my tests, it added the new row way too fast to even bother timing it.
Option Explicit

Sub AddTableRowTest()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Set myTable = AttachToTable("test_table")
    
    Dim lRow As ListRow
    Set lRow = myTable.ListRows.Add
    Debug.Print "the table now has " & myTable.ListRows.Count & " rows"
End Sub

Function AttachToTable(ByVal tableName As String) As ListObject
    Dim theTable As ListObject
    On Error Resume Next
    Set theTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If theTable Is Nothing Then
        Set theTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(10, 4))
        theTable.Name = tableName
    End If
    Set AttachToTable = theTable
End Function


Not sure what content you have in your workbook, but you can speed up things by setting:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
and when done setting these to:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

The initial post says: recently has become exceedingly slow, so it's not linked to missed optimizations, it's due to an update of Excel that greatly decreased the performance of an existing project. I'm also impacted by the bad update, and my application do set Application.ScreenUpdating = False when doing operations.
